# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method "int com.codename1.s.aw.aa()" on a null object reference

Tags: codenameone

Is this a bug, a limit on performance, or a developer error? This is thrown very rarely from some of my users that use very rich HTML5 canvases. It shouldn't be a CN1 error since it's an embedded browser, right? I have been able to replicate and it is thrown straight out of the browser view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @JAnton we need the full stack for this as this is obfuscated code. You need to connect your device with a cable and get the full printout from the console or use the native crash logging library

Comment: I will add the native log library to a release and see if I start getting something as it's very random and can't really replicate well